# Xcode on Mac App Store requires additional storage even though I have more than enough?

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore, storage

[image]
As you can see, when I try to install Xcode 9.0.1, I'm shown an error that says I need an additional 5.6 GB of free space on my drive, yet I have 10.98 GB available, and the App Store lists Xcode as only requiring 5.46 GB of space.

So why can't I download it?

Comment: I have the same issue.